# Using .get() to retrieve an array of all file names in a folder on my server

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm able to display a list of all the files in a folder on my server with this code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.get("/mockups/bryan/file_list/", function(allFiles) {
    $("#fileNames").append(allFiles);
    console.log(allFiles);
  });
})
```

However, the data it retrieves is a fully formatted web page generated by my server, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<html>
 <head>
  <title>Index of /mockups/bryan/file_list</title>
 </head>
 <body>
<h1>Index of /mockups/bryan/file_list</h1>
<pre><img src="/icons/blank.gif" alt="Icon "> <a href="?C=N;O=D">Name</a>                    <a href="?C=M;O=A">Last modified</a>      <a href="?C=S;O=A">Size</a>  <a href="?C=D;O=A">Description</a><hr><img src="/icons/back.gif" alt="[PARENTDIR]"> <a href="/mockups/bryan/">Parent Directory</a>                             -   
<img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"> <a href="092018-powersale_CTA.jpg">092018-powersale_CTA..&gt;</a> 2018-09-19 09:57  7.2K  
<img src="/icons/image2.gif" alt="[IMG]"> <a href="092018-powersale_cat1.jpg">092018-powersale_cat..&gt;</a> 2018-09-19 09:26   41K 
...
```

I only want an array containing the names of all the files in that folder so I can create my own page for displaying and linking to them.

Is there a better way to do this? Maybe .get() is the wrong tool to use, or maybe I'm using it wrong. (Or both.) I was about to dig in with some RegEx stuff to extract the info I want, but then thought "there *has* to be a better way!"

Comment: What's the code on the server-side? It looks like there is no server-side code, you're just reading a folder ..? You need some back-end code to create a response you want.

Comment: You need the data to come from server but what you are getting is a default html file generated by server. Normally you don't want those to be exposed for security reasons and can configure server not to display them. Typically you would use a server side programming language to read the directory for what you are wanting and make your request to that script

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have access to the server to do any server-side stuff (not that it would do me any good if I did). And this is only accessible on my company LAN, so there's not a security risk - and this is only enabled on a specific folder that only contains stuff that gets seen by the public anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there's a better way than RegExp. Create a [documentFragment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DocumentFragment) from the response text, and extract the links from that. Like so:

```
$.get("/mockups/bryan/file_list/", function (allFiles) {
    let fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
    let wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    let fileNames = [];
    // Put allFiles to the newly-created div
    wrapper.innerHTML = allFiles;
    // Append the elements from the div to the documentFragment
    Array.from(wrapper.childNodes).forEach(node => 
        fragment.appendChild(node);
    });
    // Collect links, and extract hrefs to fileNames array
    let links = fragment.querySelectorAll('a');
    let len = links.length;
    for (let n = 5; n < len; n++) { // Starting from 5 excludes the list headers
        fileNames.push(links[n].getAttribute('href'));
    }
    // Append filenames list to the page
    $("#fileNames").append(fileNames.join('<br>'));
});
```

**WARNING!** For the local network use only. This code is not recommended to read folder contents at a public web server, use server-side code to send filenames to clients.

It's a bit hackish to add the DTD and html, head and body tags to a div, but setting innerHTML will remove these tags, and only the relevant content is added.

I've extracted the filenames from the href attributes, but if the link texts are decent, you can use `textContent` property instead of `getAttribute` method. Reading `href` property of the link usually adds the full path to the value.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a shot. This whole project is kinda hackish anyway, so I'm ok with that. :)